# Javascript Looping through JSON an array of object s

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

so i have a login form , and i want to check whether the entered name and password already exists in the JSON object , it will prompt a different message for both cases but thr problem is it's not doing it right , here's the code for more clarity :

```
     function registerInfo(){
     var name = document.forms[0].username.value;
     var pw = document.forms[0].pw.value

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(response);

    if (name === "" || pw === "") {
    alert ('please complete all the forms')
    } 

    for (var i = 0; i < response.loginfo.length; i++){
      if ( name === response.loginfo[i].username && pw === 
            response.loginfo[i].password) {
        alert('Welcome back ' + name);
        break;
        } // if statement curly braces
    } // loop curcly braces 

    for (var i = 0; i < response.loginfo.length; i++){
        if ( name != response.loginfo[i].username && pw != response.loginfo[i].pw){
        alert('Welcome here new ');
        break;
        } // if statement curcly braces 
        } // for 
      } // ready state if statement curly braces
    } // function curly braces
    xhttp.open("GET", "login.json", true);
    xhttp.send();

    return false;
   }
```

and here's the JSON Object for a quick test

```
     {
      "loginfo" : [
      { 
          "username" : "moh",
          "password" : "lol"
      },
      {
          "username" : "zaki",
          "password" : "123"
      }         
      ]
      }
```

the problem is when the user enters the username and the password which exists in the JSON object id does alert "Welcome back!" , but also the "welcome here new" , which i don't want to , since the latest alert is for new user which their credentials doesn't exist in the JSON object.

Comment: Where would you be using this? Why aren't you doing this on a server?

Comment: Simplest fix - Instead of `break` in the first loop, use `return`.

Comment: i'm actually building a small quizz application to apply things i've learnt about js , so i'm running this on localhost and playing around with the basic stuff !

Comment: @Luca, I believe they _are_ doing it on a server, that is what the XMLHttpRequest object is about.

Comment: @Bjonnfesk it's a localhost !

Comment: What I meant was sending the client a List of all usernames and passwords

Comment: OMG lol @gurvinder372 , it worked haha , thanks a lot ! , but why return instead of break? can you explain me the logic of the wrote with break vs the one with return?

Comment: @ZakariaSichaib I have explained in the answer below.

Comment: _That_ is a very good question, and an even more important one than you made it sound :)

Comment: @ZakariaSichaib Yes, I realised that from the relative URL of the JSON file; however, being localhost doesn't preclude it from being a server, especially in the context of asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest fix would be not allows second for-loop to be executed, if a match is found, so

- Either set a flag if match is found and don't execute second for-loop if that flag is set.
- `Return` instead of break from first for-loop.

**But, you can make your code less verbose** by using `Array.prototype.some` to check if any value matches

```
var hasMatch = response.loginfo.some( s => s.username === name && s.password === pw );
```

`hasMatch` returns `true` if the match is found

```
alert( "Welcome " + (hasMatch ? "back" + name : "here new" ) );
```

Comment: Array.prototype.some is a new feature in ES6? no?

Comment: No some is there since es5, but arrow functions are from es6

Comment: so you mean that a return statement means that any loop after the actual loop won't be executed in the code?

Comment: @ZakariaSichaib Yes, after `return` no other statement in that `function` is executed.

Comment: one more question , what's the key thing to actually learn and understand the language? typically " keep building things"?

Comment: I guess it takes time and effort like anything else. MDN (mozilla developer network) is a good place to start.